# Clipping fishnet in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, vector-grid

I have created a fishnet around a city-plan.

[image: Fishnet]

Because the fishnet is huge, the loading time is of course also big, too big to continue working smoothly.

So I'd like to clip the fishnet to only the zone of the city I need:

[image: Marked area]

So I become something like this when zoomed in:
[image: Area]

So I assume I'll need the Clip tool for this, but based on what "Clip Feature" can I clip the fishnet? 
Probably some kind of square, but how do I sketch my desired square?

Comment: You probably don't want Clip. Instead, select for spatial overlap and export the selected shapes. The key to using large feature classes is to ***not*** use them -- set scale dependency so they only draw small subsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to make a smaller square or rectangle, I would simply select the points that I want to keep using the Select Features tool and then right click the fishnet layer -> Selection -> Create Layer From Selected Features.

Comment: As simple as effective, don't know why I didn't think about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your choice "to clip the fishnet to only the zone of the city" maybe to use the [Grid Index Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/grid-index-features.htm) tool instead of Create Fishnet:

> Creates a grid of rectangular polygon features that can be used as an
>   index to specify pages for a map book using Data Driven Pages. A grid
>   can be created that only includes polygon features that intersect
>   another feature layer.

You can use your "zone of the city" to limit grid creation to just those cells that overlap your "zone of the city".

Comment: I tried this, but I really need the fishnet "points" and not only the grids. Thanks for the suggestion!